# In readr()/read_csv, how to import data with all columns as character

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

In readr()/read_csv, how to import data  with  all columns as character? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)    
read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv")))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pick a default column type using:

`read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))`

The `cols` specification will also let you define specific columns as well.

Comment: Thanks, I want all columns as character.  "Unnamed `col_types` should have the same length as `col_names`. Using smaller of the two. " only return one column

Comment: Bollocks. I think they changed this behavior at some point. Looks like this will accomplish what you'd like: `read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))`